# powershell script when executing gives me execution policy change dialog

Tags: powershell

this is first part of the script

```
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Scope LocalMachine -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

..rest of script..
```

Why i get message

> The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks .....

I must somehow bypass it and run as admin

Comment: `-Force -Scope LocalMachine` aren't supported _CLI_ parameters (you cannot directly pass them to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)); just `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, which only applies to the process being created, should be enough.

Comment: i tried and no help, so i did in old fashion way, two files, one .bat and one .ps1 and thats how i did it